# JSX element type 'ModalComponent' does not have any construct or call signatures

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx

[image]

```
interface ModalType {
  component: JSX.Element;
  props: object;
}
function Modal({ title, message, onConfirm }: ModalProps) {
  const [modal, setModal] = useState<ModalType|{}>({});
  // useEffect(()=> {
  //   ModalServcie.on('open', (({ component, props })) => {
  //     setModal({
  //       component
  //       props,
  //       close: () => {
  //         setModal({});
  //       }
  //     })
  //   })
  // },[]);

  const ModalComponent = (modal as ModalType).component ? (modal as ModalType).component : null;
  return (
    <ModalContainer>
      {
        ModalComponent && (
          <ModalComponent 
            { ...modal.props }
            close={ modal.close }
            className={ ModalComponent ? 'd-block' : '' }
          />
        )
      }
    </ModalContainer>
  );
}
```

I think there's an error because the modal component can be null.

Is it a problem that the correct object value was not added when setting the model state for the first time?

I thought it’s ambiguous to initialize state to a specific value before receiving props in useEffect.

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue while using **'react-scroll'** component **Link**. I observed when I modified my import statement as :

```
import {Link} from "react-scroll";
```

After this modification, the error was resolved.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try declaring the type and only rendering the component if it actually exists:

```
  const ModalComponent: React.Component | null = (modal as ModalType).component;
  if (ModalComponent) {
    return (
      <ModalContainer>
        <ModalComponent 
          {...modal.props}
          close={modal.close}
          className='d-block'
        />
      </ModalContainer>
    );
  } else {
    return <ModalContainer></ModalContainer>;
  }
```

Comment: HI. I tried this, but got this error message.

const ModalComponent: React.Component<{}, {}, any> | null
Type 'ReactElement<any, any>' is missing the following properties from type 'Component<{}, {}, any>': context, setState, forceUpdate, render, and 2 more.ts(2740)